# Security center api token request

Tags: python-3.x, api, securitycenter

this is my code:

```
    import requests

param = {

            "username" : "login",

            "password" : "password",


}
header = {
            "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

r=requests.post("https://adres/rest/token", headers=header,params=param)
print(r.status_code)
```

And this is a result of this code:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\holkam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\holkam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\holkam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\holkam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 356, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\holkam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 372, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\holkam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\holkam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\holkam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)
```

I am trying to get a token from Security center using API and python3 according to documentation I need to issue a content type and credentials, but like above it is not working :(

Comment: You could try disable verification like this: `r=requests.post("https://adres/rest/token", headers=header,params=param, verify=False)` but it is rather a  workaround.

Comment: Also *maybe* the API you trying to call has self-signed certificate and because of that `requests` cannot verify it.

Comment: Works well thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like API you're calling has self-signed certificate. Workaround you can use in this case:

```py
r=requests.post("https://adres/rest/token", headers=header,params=param, verify=False)
```

`verify=False` would not check SSL certificate for validity.